# c++ invalid operands of types 'char*' and 'const char [2]' to binary 'operator+'

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, char, constants

the compiler return me the error "invalid operands of types 'char*' and 'const char [2]' to binary 'operator+'" when trying to do this simple code:

```
BodyText[client] = PS3::ReadString(0x0178646c) + "\n" ;
```

Here my ReadString() function:

```
char returnRead[100];
char* ReadString(int address)
{
    memset(&returnRead[0], 0, sizeof(returnRead));
    int strlength = 100;
    char* StrBytes = ReadBytes(address, strlength);
    for (int i = 0; i < strlength; i++)
    {
        if (StrBytes[i] != 0x00)
            returnRead[i] = StrBytes[i];
    else
        break;
}
return returnRead;
}
```

Thanks anyway for reading

Comment: You can't concatenate C-style strings with `+`. Use `std::string`.

Comment: This isn't a bad question, strings aren't easy/intuitive in C++.

Comment: @MichaelJones Real strings are. Only people using C++ as C with classes run into problems like this. (Well, and if you have to implement your on standard library maybe, but that's a couple of guys worldwide.)

Comment: solved with this: std::string x = PS3::ReadString(0x0178646c) + "\n" + PS3::ReadString(0x178BC74) + "\n" + PS3::ReadString(0x179147C) + "\n" + PS3::ReadString(0x1796C84) + "\n" sorry for my stupidity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because there is no `operator+` for `char*` (the return-type of your function) and `const char[2]` (the type of `"\n"`), and since you cannot overload operators for built-in types, there cannot be one. Since this question is tagged C++:

Just use `std::string` instead of `char*`, all your problems are solved already. `std::string` will be superior to the hacks you try to do.

[Here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) you can find a overview over `strings` features and examples how to use them. You then can concatenate strings `a,b,c` like `std::string new_string = a + b + c;`

Comment: how can I concatenate this??

Comment: i tried with this:                                                     std::string x = "\n";
  char *y = PS3::ReadString(0x0178646c);
  std::strcpy(y, x.c_str());
delete[] y;

Comment: If you can change `ReadBytes`, have it return a `std::string` and forget about `char*`, `memset`, `fscanf` and all this C-style stuff for now. It is unnecessarily hard to get right and does not benefit you.